# The auto prettier in Reactjs breaks the line

Tags: reactjs, prettier

This is the original code without auto-saving prettier.

```
const Register = () => (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <nav className="row bg-white border-bottom">
        <div className="col text-secondary logotype">
          logo
        </div>
        <div className="col-6 text-secondary text-center menu">
          register
        </div>
        <div className="col text-right clock">
        </div>
      </nav>
   </div>
```

After auto-saving with prettier in vscode, it works weird.
Could you recommend the solution?

```
const Register = () => ( <
  div className = "container-fluid" >
  <
  nav className = "row bg-white border-bottom" >
  <
  div className = "col text-secondary logotype" >
  logo <
  /div> <
  div className = "col-6 text-secondary text-center menu" >
  register <
  /div> <
  div className = "col text-right clock" >
  <
  /div> <
  /nav> <
```

> I solved this problem by eliminating Buefy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to your `.editorconfig`

```
 `jsxBracketSameLine: true`
```

More info and examples about this [PrettierConfig](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#jsx-brackets) for jsxBracket

if you don't have `.editorconfig` then open VSCode's `settings.json` set

```
 prettier.jsxBracketSameLine: true
```

more info about prettier [VSCode settings](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#prettierjsxbracketsameline-default-false) for jsxBracket

Answer (score -1):

**Perfect way to Use Prettier with VS Code**

Install the Prettier and ESLint VS Code Extensions

Install the following Visual Studio Code Extensions:

1. ESLint
2. Prettier

Create an .eslintrc file with the following contents:

```
{
  "extends": "react-app",
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  }
}
```

If you are not happy with the default Prettier configuration then you can create a .prettierrc file with your own options, for example:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5"
}
```

**Apply Prettier Formatting on Save (Optional)**

You most likely want to apply the Prettier formatting whenever you save your files. To do so, add the following to your Visual Studio Code Workspace Settings:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

**Prevent Prettier Violations from being Committed (Optional)**

To prevent unformatted code from being committed to Git you can add a pre-commit hook. There are a few ways to do this, I will show the steps using pretty-quick and husky setup (option 2). I have gone with this option as pretty-quick respects the .prettierrc file.

**Note:** Your Git repository must already be initialised, otherwise the precommit hooks will not be installed by husky.

**Install the packages:**

```
yarn add --dev pretty-quick husky
```

Then add the husky section to your package.json file:

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
 }
```

You're good to go!